# Enforcing type safety across typedefs of the same primitive type?

Tags: c++

I have two typedefs like so:

```
typedef int16_t X;
typedef int16_t Y;
```

However, I want to enforce type safety between X and Y, so that the compiler doesn't replace each X and Y with int16_t and then allows an X instead of a Y type.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Not with typedefs. You will have to define your own types.

Comment: Does anyone know why this isn't the case? It seems like such an obvious thing for the compiler to be able to do.

Comment: @James: historical reasons, but it's because typedefs were first invented merely as an alias for a type, and probably some things rely on that. It does cause problems for example when you accidentally write some code that stores a `uint32_t` in an `unsigned int`, and the compiler can't warn you even with all conversion warnings turned on, because on this implementation those are the same type.

Answer (score 1):

No `typedef`s are just an alias for the type.  You'd have to use `class` wrappers to get truely different types.

Comment: I have been advised this would inhibit the compiler's ability to optimise?

Comment: @user997112: check the emitted code, but some compilers are smarter than others at working their way through an extra level of abstraction. You certainly can't rule out the possibility that some compilers will do better with some expressions using `int` than they would with the same expression using a wrapper type. Even once everything is inlined, the wrapping function calls introduce in some cases additional sequencing that an integer type doesn't have, for example, which could in principle affect what the optimizer manages.

Comment: @user997112 I don't see why It would, the compiler can't mix and match the two as they're different types but it's free to optimise away the wrapper (if it wants to)